# copy User Interface Broken on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: clipboard

copyQ clipboard software User Interface Broken on Ubuntu 16.04 like this image. I have re-installed several times but user interface same. How do I fix this ?

[image]

Comment: Not a fix but a friendly message. Just a reminder 16.04 reaches end of standard support on April 22 2021. You may want to think about upgrading to 18.04 or 20.04. End of Stand Support means no more support or updates. You may not ask questions here either as 16.04 will be off topic. If you sign up for ESM you can still get security patches but that is all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will.